# Include item in TOC, but not exactly chapter. In memoir

Tags: memoir

I need to include these "Thanks" and "Introduction" chapter in the TOC, on the other hand I do not want it to have the normal chapter numbering and other characteristics so I included it like this:
 `\chapter*{Agradecimentos}` which fits perfectly my needs but the inclusion in the TOC.

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[14pt,twoside,a5paper,extrafontsizes, draft, showtrims]{memoir}
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
        \tableofcontents
        \chapter*{Agradecimentos}
        \chapter*{Introdução}
        \chapter{Preparação}
        \chapter{Conhecimento}
        \chapter{Influências}
\end{document}
```

Is there way to include these "Thanks" and "Introduction" in the TOC without being numbered as chapters?

Comment: Also, I would like to center align the `\frontmatter` TOC items.....
Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easy way is to use the `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter` commands to separate your preface content from the main body of your document. Pages in the front matter are Roman-numbered, but chapters are un-numbered. Main matter pages are Arabic-numbered, and chapters are numbered.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents* % so ToC doesn't contain itself
\chapter{Thanks}
\mainmatter
\chapter{One}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great.
Is there a way to identify it by numbered pages instead of Roman-numbered?

Comment: I am using memoir and thatcher...I believe that is why it is ALREADY showing numbers instead of Romans.